# Правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: стилистика

Правильно ли составлено предложение:
«Законодатель в принципиальном плане не определяет конкретных обстоятельств, при которых следует возбуждать уголовное дело по факту совершения преступления, а в каких ­ в отношении конкретного лица»?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, не совсем. Лучше так:«законодатель в принципиальном плане не определяет конкретных обстоятельств,при которых следует возбуждать уголовное дело по факту совершения преступления или ­ в отношении конкретного лица»

Или так:  «законодатель в принципиальном плане не определяет конкретных обстоятельств, при которых следует возбуждать уголовное дело:(возможно и тире)  в каких по факту совершения преступления, а в каких  - ­ в отношении конкретного лица»

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложила такой вариант.

Законодатель четко не определяет, при каких обстоятельствах следует возбуждать уголовное дело по факту совершения преступления, а при каких - в отношении конкретного лица.

Answer (score 1):

А слово "план" здесь никому не показалось неуместным? Каков вообще смысл словосочетания "в принципиальном плане" - "принципиально" не определяет (то есть намеренно) или как еще?

Answer (score 0):

Фраза подлежит правке. Если максимально близко к исходному, то так:

*«Законодатель в принципиальном плане не определяет конкретных обстоятельств, при которых следует возбуждать уголовное дело по факту совершения преступления, а **при которых** - в отношении конкретного лица».* Противопоставление "при которых" - "в каких" косноязычно.  С тире в "а при каких - в отношении конкретного лица" полностью согласен, без него - неправильно.

А если вообще говорить... Слишком тяжеловесна, пожалуй, для нормального языка, но что с юристов взять, от них не и такого услышишь. Хотелось бы понять еще, "принципиальный план" - это что за зверь такой? Интуитивно чувствую, что предложенная замена на "четко не определяет" не совсем точна по смыслу. Возможно, здесь речь идёт о том, что Законодатель именно что не "формулирует принципов", нет?!

Comment: Если речь именно про принципы, то да. Можно оставить.